# Angular 2 - Fallback route not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-routing

I have an Angular2 project built with this [Angular 2 Webpack Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) but I cannot get the fallback route to work correctly.  In my `app.routes.ts` I have:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home';
import { DataResolver } from './app.resolver';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
     path: '',
     component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
     path: 'getstarted', loadChildren: './getstarted#GetStartedModule'
  },

  ...
  {
     path: 'notfound', loadChildren: './notfound#NotFoundModule'
  },
  {
     path: '**', loadChildren: './notfound#NotFoundModule'
  },
];
```

The `not found` path above works correctly but the fallback route (`**`) does not work correctly.  Instead of showing the `NotFoundModule` it does not load a module at all and I get no errors.  However, when I do this it redirects correctly:

```
  ...
  {
     path: 'notfound', loadChildren: './notfound#NotFoundModule'
  },
  {
    path: '**', redirectTo:'/notfound', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
];
```

I do not want to redirect though because I do not want to change the url to `/notfound` by redirecting.  How can I make my top version work or what else can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I just tried it and it seems that you cannot use lazy routes to set your fallback page. This should work :

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
     path: '',
     component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
     path: 'getstarted', loadChildren: './getstarted#GetStartedModule'
  },

  ...
  {
     path: 'notfound', loadChildren: './notfound#NotFoundModule'
  },
  {
     path: '**', component : NotFoundComponent
  },
];
```